# Loop through ajax values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some values that are returned to ajax from backend.
The problem in this code is that when I do console.log(myRows) the values in cells are undefined.

```
  $(document).on('click', ".myButton", function () {



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Administration.aspx/GetMyCollection",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'Parameter': Parameter }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    var myRows = "";

                    $.each(data, function (i, values) {

                        values.ObjectID;
                        values.ObjectName;
                        values.ObjectValue;
                        values.Object;
                        console.log(values);

                        myRows += "<tr><td>" + values[1].ID + "</td><td>" + values[1].ObjectName + "</td><td>" + values[1].ObjectValue + "</td><td>" + values[1].Object + "</td></tr>";
                        console.log(myRows);
                    });

                }
                console.log("Saved!");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Not Saved!");
           }

        });
    });
```

But when I change the code and add values[1], the values are displayed correctly.

```
 myRows += "<tr><td>" + values[1].ID + "</td><td>" + values[1].ObjectName + "</td><td>" + values[1].ObjectValue + "</td><td>" + values[1].Object + "</td></tr>";
```

I need help to change the code so it will loop through all 9 (from 1 to 9) values and places the results in myRows cells so all the values can be displayed.

Json code:

```
d   […]
0   {…}
ObjectID      1
ObjectName    Vegas
ObjectValue   234
Object        Arizona
1   {…}
ObjectID      2
ObjectName    Chicago
ObjectValue   211
Object        Montana
2   {…}
ObjectID      3
ObjectName    Livepool
ObjectValue   123
Object        London
...
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you please add sample value of `data`?

Comment: **console.log(myRows) the values in cells are undefined.** and **But when I change the code and add values[1], the values are displayed correctly.** - Statements are conflicting. As in code as well you are using `values[1]`

Comment: I added the values that need to be displayed. Can you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looping over the right item - `$.each(data` should be `$.each(data.d` since `d` contains the array. Then each time the loop runs `values` will represent one individual object from the array, and you can removed the `[1]` from your code.

Also `values.ID` should be `values.ObjectID` I think, based on the data sample you give in the question - there's no "ID" property on any of your objects.

Lastly I took the liberty of moving `console.log(myRows);` to after the end of the loop - then you'll just see the whole string once, not get it repeated each time with an extra bit added, which might be confusing.

```
$.each(data.d, function (i, values) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
  myRows += "<tr><td>" + values.ObjectID + "</td><td>" + values.ObjectName + "</td><td>" + values.ObjectValue + "</td><td>" + values.Object + "</td></tr>";
});
console.log(myRows);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are iterating over the array, `values` will hold the object. Hence, you do not need to use `values[i]` or `values[1]`. Additionally, it seems you have data in `data.d` and hence, should iterate on that.

Hence, you can update your code to following

```
$.each(data.d, function (i, values) {
  myRows += "<tr><td>" + values.ObjectID + "</td><td>" + values.ObjectName + "</td><td>" + values.ObjectValue + "</td><td>" + values.Object + "</td></tr>";
});
console.log(myRows);
```

**Note**, add your log after the `each` block to see complete set of rows.

Answer (score 0):

use function like this to make tr string

```
var myRows = "";
data.forEach(function (values,key) {
    myRows += "<tr><td>" + values.ID + "</td><td>" + values.ObjectName + "</td><td>" + values.ObjectValue + "</td><td>" + values[1].Object + "</td></tr>";
    console.log(myRows);
});
```